# Rails 5 - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create a form for the **edit view** but I'm getting the "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty".

I have a similar form for the **new view** that works with:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>
```

I would like to use a shared form for **both the edit and new** but I can't manage to retrieve the @user to make it work. Thanks for your help!

views/user/edit.html.erb >

```
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

users_controller.rb >

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'There was an error updating your account, try again'
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

routes.rb >

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form is on the `edit` action, not `update`.

Thus, you need to add the `edit` action, from which the `@user` instance variable will be taken:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```